# Processing JSON in Azure

Tags: json, azure, parsing, logic

Making an Azure Logic App, I am attempting to parse incoming files, but keep getting the error message:

> BadRequest. The property 'content' must be of type JSON in the
>   'ParseJson' action inputs, but was of type
>   'application/octet-stream'.

No matter how I set my source input formatting. The content in the file looks like this:

```
{
  "Real01": 39439.4140625,
  "DINT01": 24494,
  "String01": "EVENT! - DI01 Swithed ON at PLC Time:  122812",
  "Bit01": true
}
```

Any ideas how to get it to recognize the contents the way they are, or what to insert in the source file or in the Logic App flow, to enable the parser to read my files? I should add that I have used a sample payload to generate the schema, so it puzzles me that this does not just work right away.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems similar to HTTP's `Content-Type` header (in HTTP's case the `application/octet-stream` value usually triggers a download in browsers for example). The correct content type for JSON content should be `application/json`.

You need to check if you can update the MIME type of the files you are reading (for example, Azure Blob files MIME type is usually, by default, set to `application/octet-stream`).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. As it turned out, I needed to "JSONify" the contents of the file using a function, even though the content was already JSON. Well, you learn something every day. I found out this could be a necessary step from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtDEpbCw6oQ